# JPA Map One Table Multiple Rows as a Many-to-One

Tags: jpa, mapping

I have a use-case where I would like to map one table's multiple rows as one Entity, having a list of either @OneToMany or @ElementCollection.

Here is my table:

```
company | name | detail | detail_value |
1       | C1   | d1     | 100          |
1       | C1   | d2     | 200          |
2       | C2   | d1     | 500          |
```

So here I would ideally want to map it in the following manner:

```
class CompanyDetails {
 Long companyId;
 List<Detail> details;
}

class Detail {
  String detail;
  Double value;
}
```

Why do I want do it like this ? Because I want to put some business and validation logic in the CompanyDetails, that acts as a sort of an aggregate root.

Thank you in advance for your kind help.
Best Regards,
Aleks

Comment: The why explanation is lacking: most DB designs would have you normalize the company id/name into a company table and have a company details table reference it. What you've got instead is a 'detail' table that doesn't really have any 'company' instance to reference - the company id/name pair is really an embedded object dependent on the Detail, not the other way around. Your DB is a bit disconnected with the model, as you have no way of handling detail rows with the same company id value, but different names

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first comment above - without normalization and primary key you cannot modify the data correctly. But if you need only read entities from DB, that would work (sorry for Kotlin):

```
@Entity
@Subselect("select distinct id, name from company")
open class Company {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    open var id: Long? = null

    @Column(name = "name")
    open var name: String? = null

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "company",
            joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "id")],
            foreignKey = ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)
    )
    open var details: MutableSet<CompanyDetails> = mutableSetOf()
}

@Embeddable
open class CompanyDetails {

    @Column(name = "detail")
    open var detail: String? = null

    @Column(name = "detail_value")
    open var value: String? = null

}
```